# How to fetch distance using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have this URL

```
http://www.worldatlas.com/travelaids/driving_distance.htm
```

when I put

```
From city:
Hollywood, FL, United States
to city:
Washington Avenue, Miami Beach, FL, United States
```

I am getting a distance of `18.33mi / 29.51km`

I require a php script which will send that url these above two addresses and in return I will get the above distance.
I heard that by using CURL we can get this please help/guide ,

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
$origin = urlencode("Hollywood, FL");
$destination = urlencode("Washington Avenue, Miami Beach, FL");
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$origin&destination=$destination&sensor=false";
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
$arr = json_decode($output, TRUE);
echo "";
print_r($arr); //get distance from this array

Ref: [Google Maps Directions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) Hope it helps

Comment: Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day.

Comment: @user1133643 - what's your point?

Answer (score 2):

I think Google API will help you on this.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Also I think this guide will help you a little.

http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/

Comment: Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day.

Comment: If you are getting more than 2,500 user search per day means your web site is very popular and could be profitable. So in that case you can get a business version. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/ 

And if you try to do this using worldatlas web site you have to keep your eye on them often. Because if they modified their search criteria your site will also need changes. And if they found that your server IP generates more than 2500 requests per day to their server there is a possibility to get blocked..

Comment: very correct so I think must go 4 premium package..... thanks 4 this help  :)